# Celery tasks being sent to multiple queues

Tags: python, redis, celery

I've noticed that celery has been sending tasks to multiple queues, and workers on both queues have been executing the tasks.

My queue definitions are:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('client1', Exchange('client1'), routing_key='client1'),
    Queue('images', Exchange('media'), routing_key='media.images'),
)
```

And when, after stopping all my workers, I run:

```
>>> tasks.ping.apply_async(queue='default')
```

I can see the task appear in *both* the `default` and `client1` queues:

```
$ redis-cli -c llen default
(integer) 1
$ redis-cli -c llen client1
(integer) 1
```

This only applies to the `default` queue. Sending it directly to the `client1` queue only adds it there:

```
>>> tasks.ping.apply_async(queue='client1')
$ redis-cli -c llen default
(integer) 1
$ redis-cli -c llen client1
(integer) 2
```

The `images` queue never receives tasks incorrectly.

This is Celery 3.1.15 with the Redis broker.

Answer (score 8):

Okay! It looks like the problem is that Kombu's Redis broker doesn't clear old exchanges + routing keys.

Initially I had configured the queues:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('client1', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
)
```

And later changed them to use a separate exchange and routing key for `client1`.

But for some reason Kombu didn't clear out the old bindings, so I was left with:

```
redis> smembers _kombu.binding.default
1) "default\x06\x16\x06\x16client1"
2) "default.client1\x06\x16\x06\x16client1"
3) "default\x06\x16\x06\x16default"
```

So tasks sent to `default` were being routed to both the `default` and `client1` queues.

The fix was to remove the incorrect bindings:

```
redis> srem _kombu.binding.default "default\x06\x16\x06\x16client1"
redis> srem _kombu.binding.default "default.client1\x06\x16\x06\x16client1"
```